# How to do Zoomable?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an app with some questions; but to read the question , we need to zoom on each image.

How can I put a zoom on the image, on order to read it? Thanks; step-by-step, please.

```
<RelativeLayout>
      <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/t1"
                android:id="@+id/i1"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/t2"
                android:id="@+id/i2" />

        </LinearLayout>    
    </ScrollView>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: im using a scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Try using object animator. This may help you.

```
        ObjectAnimator scaleUpY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY",5f);
    ObjectAnimator scaleUpX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX",5f);
    scaleUpY.setDuration(1000);
    scaleUpX.setDuration(1000);
    AnimatorSet scaleUp = new AnimatorSet();
    scaleUp.play(scaleUpX).with(scaleUpY);
    scaleUp.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement yourself, you can look at the [ZoomableDraweeView from facebook fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/zoomable/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/zoomable/ZoomableDraweeView.java).

For simplicity, you can use [PhotoView by chrisbanes](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView).

Wish helps.